# how to link banner logo image to home.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want my website banner logo to redirect to home.php. I'm presently using this code in codeigniter header file

```
<div class="fleft">
  <h1 class="logo">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/Green-Surfer- 
      Png.png')?>" id ="Green Surfer Logo" alt="Green Surfer">
    </a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: you want an image to redirect? are you sure you don't mean you want to make the href go to home.php? what is the issue here?

Comment: Why are you not adding this in your a tag href? `<?php echo base_url('home.php'); ?>`

Comment: btw, your id="Green Surfer Logo" is not valid:  `the id value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty) and it can’t contain any space characters`, so id="Green_Surfer_Logo" would be valid

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div class="fleft">
   <h1 class="logo">
      <a href="<?= base_url('controller/function')?>">
         <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/Green-Surfer-Png.png')?>" id ="Green Surfer Logo" alt="Green Surfer">
      </a> 
   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @khalidaJunedSheikh accept the answer and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "base_url()" function, it is defined in config/config.php:

```
  <a href="<?php base_url('controller/method')?>">
     <img src="xyz.jpg" alt="banner">
  </a>
```